# Ember Component event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a couple of questions related to Ember Component event handling

1. Did "Ember Components" support direct event handling from the very initial versions OR was it added in later releases ?
2. Referring to the following page
   https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Component
   There is a Form events section. I wanted to understand what native event does the component event actually get attached to. e.g. 'input' event.
   Could not find the specific event in their documentation.

Comment: The events are listed at the very end of the [page you linked](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Component#event-names). The methods inside a component are available since Ember Components are a thing or maybe even before that. You can also check out the source for the [EventDispatcher](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/67bf23f2b0a9ed42bd6ccfcdb82aa9e89798bb52/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js#L63)

Comment: Thx. So does the 'input' event refer to jquery input event ?

Comment: Yes. Which in turn refers to the DOM Event of the same Name. Starting with Ember 3 those events do no longer rely on jQuery but use their native equivalents.

Comment: Oh...never realized that 'input' is also native JS event...So from Ember 3, they'll directly use the native JS events internally ?

Comment: `thing.addEventListener('input',...` = `thing.on('input',...` kinda thing, right? --- but also, it's not that cut and dry. Using those in the template is a little confusing because of the camelCase vs Kabob. Docs say keyPress etc / and the template usage would be with dashes.

Comment: @testndtv stating from 3.0 Ember includes [ember-native-dom-event-dispatcher](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-native-dom-event-dispatcher) which replaces the jQuery dispatcher used before that. This is one step necessary to remove jQuery from an Ember project. The future is bright.

Comment: Oh cool...I never realized that Ember had a plan to ultimately replace jQuery entirely as a dependency !